# How to get different lists of file paths depending on subdirs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, path, os.walk

```
-Root
--A
---1,2
--B
---3
```

I am trying to get a list of lists of paths based on subdirs:

`[['Root/A/1','Root/A/2'],['Root/B/3']]`

I tried using os.walk but I couldn't get it to work. I can get a list of all files in one giant list but I can't split those based on subdirs

```
fullList = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        for name in files:
            fullList.append(os.path.join(root, name))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have a list of lists, but you create a list of strings.  You'll need to create each of the interior lists and put them all together into one master list.

This program might do what you want:

```
import os
from pprint import pprint


def return_list_of_paths(dir='.'):
    return [[os.path.join(root, file) for file in files]
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir)
            if files]


pprint(return_list_of_paths("ROOT"))
```

Or, if you don't care for list comprehensions:

```
import os
from pprint import pprint


def return_list_of_paths(dir='.'):
    fullList = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        if files:
            oneList = []
            for file in files:
                oneList.append(os.path.join(root, file))
            fullList.append(oneList)
    return fullList


pprint(return_list_of_paths("ROOT"))
```

Comment: Hey, the first one does exactly what I want but can you walk me through that code? I am fairly new to python and couldn't really parse that piece of code. Thanks so much!

Comment: I looked that the second code block and understood what you did except for one thing: what does that "if files:' part do? Thanks!

Comment: The two versions are functionally identical. Whenever you build a list like this: `l = []; for x in y: l.append(z)` you can replace that with `l = [z for x in y]`. See [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) or google `python list comprehension` for more details.

Comment: The `if files` is to avoid adding empty sublists if you have an empty subdirectory.  Try creating an empty "C" directory and run the program with and without the `if files:` line.